# wasserstein distance between distributions with bounded ratio

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $p$ and $q$ be probability distributions on a metric space $X=(X, d)$ with densities $dp$ and $dq$, such that there exists $0 < \alpha < \beta < \infty$ satisfying

$$
\alpha d p \le dq \le \beta dp .
$$

What is an upper bound for the Wasserstein distance $W_d(p,q)$ ?

**Notes:** $W_d(p, q) := \sup_{\|f\|_{\text{Lip}} \le 1} |\mathbb E_{x \sim p}[f(x)] - \mathbb E_{x \sim q}[f(x)]|$

---

## Update

It's well known (e.g see Gabe K's response below or [Theorem 4 of this paper](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~su/papers.dir/metrics.pdf)) that

> $$
> W_d(p, q) \le \operatorname{diam}(X)\operatorname{TV}(p, q).
> $$

Thus if $X$ has finite diameter, it suffices to bound $\operatorname{TV}(p, q)$.

Recall the definition of total variation,

$$
\operatorname{TV}(p, q) := \sup_{A \subseteq X} \left|\int_A dq-\int_A dp\right|.
$$
Now, for any $A \subseteq X$, one has
$
\int_A dq - \int_A dp \ge \int_A(\alpha-1)dp = (\alpha-1)p(A).
$
Similarly, one has $\int_A dq - \int_A dp \le (\beta-1)p(A)$. Thus 
$$
\left|\int_A dq - \int_A dp \le (\beta-1)p(A)\right| \le \max(1-\alpha,\beta-1)p(A) \le \max(1-\alpha,\beta-1),
$$
and so $\operatorname{TV}(p,q) \le \max(1-\alpha,\beta-1)$. Putting things together, we get

$$
W_d(p,q) \le \operatorname{diam}(X)\max(1-\alpha,\beta-1).
$$

## Case of infinite diameter

In case of infinite diameter assuming that $p$ or $q$ satisfies a *Talagrand transportation-cost inequality*, i.e

> $$W_{d,2}(p,r)\le \sqrt{(2/\rho)\operatorname{kl}(r\|p)}
> $$
>   for some $\rho > 0$ and for any distribution $r$ on $X$ relatively continuous w.r.t $p$,

with a similar story for $q$ (e.g for standard Gaussian, this holds with $\rho=1$), allows us to still get an upper bound, namely
$$
W_{d,2}(p,q) \le  \sqrt{2\min (\beta\log(\beta)/\rho_p,(1/\alpha)\log(1/\alpha)/\rho_q)}.
$$

Comment: Do you want a bound using only $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Ya sure, a bound in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (and perhaps a the diameter of the space $X$ w.r.t $p$ ?!)    :)

Comment: Perhaps the dual form of $W_d(p,q)=\int_0^1 |F^{-1}_p(u)-F^{-1}_q(u) | \mathrm{d}u$ is useful here?

Comment: Nope. That's only valid in 1 dimension.

Comment: Does "densities" here just mean Radon-Nikodym derivatives with respect to some (unspecified, but the same for p and q) measure on $(X,d)$?

Comment: @Steve Yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

Any estimate will need to incorporate the diameter of $X$. To see this, consider the interval $[0,L]$ and the distribution with density,

$$\begin{cases} 
      \frac{2}{L} & 0 \leq x \leq L/3 \\
      \frac{1}{2L} & L/3 \leq x \leq L \\
   \end{cases} $$

One can calculate the distance from the uniform distribution $1/L$ using the dual formulation of the Wasserstein distance, and it blows up as $L$ goes to infinity. Therefore, we cannot hope for an estimate solely in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

However, assuming a bound on the diameter $D$ of $X$, then we can say more. With $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we can derive a bound on $\delta(p,q)$ the total variation distance between $p$ and $q$. One possible transfer plan from $p$ to $q$ is to move the excess mass of $p$ to $q$, fixing the overlap. The total mass to be moved then is $\delta(p,q)$, and the cost to move the mass is no more than $D^d$. Skipping some derivations, this shows that the Wasserstein 2-distance is bounded by $D \sqrt{ \delta(p,q)}$, so this gives your desired result. This can be generalized to the other Wasserstein metrics as well.

Comment: sure.  Thanks for the response (upvoted). Sure, I suspected it involve the diameter of $X$ w.r.t to $p$. See my comment section above. More precisely, it would involve something like $\sup_{x_0} \mathbb E_{x \in p} d(x,x_0)$ (which is $\le D$).

Comment: OK, i can workout $TV(p,q) \le \max(1-\alpha,\beta-1)$ and so $W_d(p,q) \le \max(1-\alpha,\beta-1)\operatorname{diam}(X)$

Comment: Also this document provides numerous useful inequalities between metrics on probability measures https://www.math.hmc.edu/~su/papers.dir/metrics.pdf. In general to upper bound $W$ metric with another metric, you need  an upper bound on the diameter of the metric space.

Comment: Actually, in case of infinite diameter assuming that $p$  and $q$ both satisfy the *Talagrand transportation-cost inequality*, i.e $W_{d,2}(p,r)\le \sqrt{(2/\rho)\operatorname{kl}(r\|p)}$ for any distribution $r$ on $X$ relatively continuous w.r.t $p$, with a similar story for $q$ (e.g for standard Gaussian, this holds with $\rho=1$), allows us to still get an upper bound, namely $w_{d,2}(p,q) \le  \sqrt{2\min (\beta\log(\beta),(1/\alpha)\log(1/\alpha))/\rho}$.

Comment: For sure. In fact, you only need to assume that either $p$ or $q$ (not both) satisfies a log-Sobolev inequality to get this. This estimate depend on the $\rho$ in the log-Sobolev inequality, so this introduces another ingredient while eliminating the diameter.

Comment: Yeah the "both" was a thinko, what I really meant was "or". :)